# Calling correctly a closure with a return

Tags: javascript, closures, return-value

This works fine:

```
var test = function(){
    var a = 0;
    console.log(a);
    return function (){
        a++;
        return a;    
    };
};

var counter = test();

console.log(counter()); //1
console.log(counter()); //2
console.log(counter()); //3
console.log(counter()); //4
```

Why cannot I get same result by:

```
console.log(test());
```

and why do I need to work through a somewhat redundant proxy here (var counter), provided that the following works OK):

```
var test = function(k,l){
    var c = k + l;
    return c;
};

console.log(test(1,2));
```

Does this have something to do with the fact that there is a closure and I am calling a function which returns a function which returns some value in the end? Do I really need to define a new variable here or I can save time and lines of code and get it work directly?

Answer (score 1):

**Does this have something to do with the fact that there is a closure and I am calling a function which returns a function which returns some value in the end?**

Yes it does. Your function `test()` does nothing else than setting up a variable, log `0` and then return another (operator) function which closes over the the scope of `test()`.

**Do I really need to define a new variable here or I can save time and lines of code and get it work directly?**

Yes again. You need to hold a reference to that returned function by `test()`, which has an active scope-chain entry. Without any active reference (like assigning it to a variable) the garbage collector would clean it up.

Comment: This is a very good explanation. So, I will end up with a global variable `counter` in my first case anyways, even having in mind an intention to avoid globals?

Comment: whether or not your variable is global, depends on you and your code. You can always enclosure your code with `(function() {}());` to create your own application scope for instance, which is common practice.

Comment: Thanks, I have heard about this approach, I think it is very tightly related to the concept of incapsulation. On another note, may be you know why calling the function directly without a proxy variable (let us put the purpose of storing the incremented value aside for now)  by running console.log(test()); produces a very strange result:   `0
function (){
        a++;
        return a;    
    }`. It logs `0` but then also logs the nested function instead of executing it and returning the result?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to do.

You first example is a counter which holds state (remembers the last value). You can have multiple counters counting different things.

The second example is a function which just adds to numbers together but doesnt hold state or do anything different next time.

If you want to have a counter but without having to create it first you can do this:

```
var total = 0;

function count(){
    total = total + 1;
    return total;
}
```

So now:

```
console.log(count()); // 1
console.log(count()); // 2
console.log(count()); // 3
```

Or hide the variable in the function:

```
function counter(){
    counter.total = (counter.total||0) + 1;
    return counter.total;
}
```

Then:

```
console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter()); // 2
console.log(counter()); // 3
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid global variables, but I guess I cannot since the interpreter will not store the value of `a` and will trash it straight after function executes. I was hoping that the fact that I refer to this variable `a` in a nested (I like to call it child) function will be somehow useful and it would not be trashed.

Comment: @Vadimster, if you want to avoid the global then I think your closure method is the best. Whats the problem with doing it that way?

Comment: @ ChrisC I still have to make a global var `var counter = test();` because, if I understand it correctly, the garbage collector will not store my `var a`, since it does not have any useful links outside and is just a local variable in a function. But once I create a reference, then I guess it is not touched.

Comment: @Vadimster, Ok I see. If you need your counter function to be global but dont want to have a separate variable then you could store it with the function. I'll edit to show this.